# ui.select giving duplicate errors and then undefined if track by $index added

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using `ui.select` which is presenting some issues.

Using the following code:

```
<ui-select multiple ng-model="$storage.SelectedClients" theme="bootstrap" style="width: 300px;">
    <ui-select-match placeholder="Search and select Clients...">{{$item.name}}</ui-select-match>
    <ui-select-choices repeat="client in $storage.Clients | propsFilter: {name: $select.search}">
        <div ng-bind-html="client.name | highlight: $select.search"></div>
        <small>
      email: {{client.email}}
      </small>
    </ui-select-choices>
</ui-select>
```

Works fine unless I have a client with the same name. I then get:

[image]

So I added `track by $index` to the end of the repeat to be given a new error.

[image]

I have tried by tracking by other things that i know are unique however I always receive this error.

My research has pointed towards similar things however nothing is working for me:

Research here:
https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select/issues/870
https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select/issues/219
https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select/issues/380

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try by adding this condition

```
if(matches!=null && matches.length>0 && result[matches[1]] == value[matches[1]]){
```

/* write your code here */

}